# how do I encode CGI arguments when constructing a java URL for eventual HTTP GET using openConnection()

Tags: java, http, cgi

I need to use java to do an HTTP GET to a CGI and pass it some parameters, one of which is itself a URL with some embedded CGI arguments.

I tried

```
String cgiArgs="client="+clientAddr+"&tag="+sessionId+"&rates="+ratesString
    +"&callbackURL="+URLEncoder.encode(callbackURL);
if (null != debugGateway)
    cgiArgs += "&gateway=" +debugGateway; // for debugging
URI u_ = new URI("http", null, "scimitar", 3000, "/igmpcgi/allocateAuxiliaryStream",
        cgiArgs, null);
URL u = u_.toURL();
URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
```

Unfortunately, the `java.net.URLEncoder.encode()` method quotes things in such a way that then end up getting quoted again during `openConnection()`.

What is the proper java way to construct a CGI argument string when some of the key=value pairs include string values that themselves have ?,&, and = characters ?